# SQL Select TOP 10 For Each Line

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am having some issue selecting the top for each line on the below code:

This would be based on LineNoID, which is the line.

```
SELECT TOP 10

        DTM.[LineNoID]          as [Line ID],
        DTM.[Fault Code]        AS [DTM Fault Code],
        DTFC.[Fault Code]       AS [DTFC Fault Code], 
        COUNT(DTM.[Fault Code]) AS [Fault Code Occurences], 
        DTFC.[Fault Name],
        SUM(DTM.[Minutes Down]) AS [Total Minutes Down]

FROM

        DTMain          AS DTM,
        DTFaultCodes    AS DTFC,
        DTLine          AS DTL

WHERE   

        DTM.[Fault Code] = DTFC.[Fault Code]

AND     

        DTM.LineNoID = DTL.[LineNoID]

AND

        DTFC.[Category] = 'E'

GROUP BY 
            DTM.[LineNoID],
            DTM.[Fault Code],
            DTFC.[Fault Code],
            DTFC.[Fault Name]           

ORDER BY [Total Minutes Down] DESC
```

I have looked over several other posts and am struggling to "convert" them into my code. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
David

---

Updated query:

```
SELECT
        [Line ID],
        [DTM Fault Code],
        [DTFC Fault Code],
        [Fault Code Occurences],
        [Total Minutes Down]
FROM
  (
SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DTM.[LineNoID] ORDER BY SUM([Minutes Down] AS [Total Minutes Down]) DESC) [Line ID],
        DTM.[LineNoID]          AS [Line ID],
        DTM.[Fault Code]        AS [DTM Fault Code],
        DTFC.[Fault Code]       AS [DTFC Fault Code], 
        COUNT(DTM.[Fault Code]) AS [Fault Code Occurences], 
        DTFC.[Fault Name]
FROM
        DTMain          AS DTM,
        DTFaultCodes    AS DTFC,
        DTLine          AS DTL
WHERE
        DTM.[Fault Code] = DTFC.[Fault Code]
AND
        DTM.LineNoID = DTL.[LineNoID]
AND
        DTFC.[Category] = 'E'
GROUP BY
            DTM.[LineNoID],
            DTM.[Fault Code],
            DTFC.[Fault Code],
            DTFC.[Fault Name]
  ) s
WHERE [Total Minutes Down] <= 10

ORDER BY [Total Minutes Down] DESC
```

It is showing "'SUM' is not a recognized built-in function name." when running the above.

Apologies for the lack of knowledge!

Comment: Is it the `TOP` function(SqlServer) you're looking for?? though you should mention your RDBMS, since it depends on it.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: @Goon10 Sorry I had forgot to add the top 10 back onto the select statement, will edit this now. With this in it is showing me the top 10 for all lines, where as I am after the top 10 faults for each line.

Comment: @marc_s thank you I will have a look over that, I have been working in a old SQL environment for quite some time. Any improvements on my SQL are appreciated! :D

Comment: To add onto that I am using MSSQL 2005, my bad!

Comment: What do you actually mean by the "top for each line" as I can see multiple possible meanings; the top 10 will return the top 10 results whereas it might be you want a summary of the top 10 lines for each row. I would also suggest you put on dummy results to demonstrate this or an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to aid those wanting to help.

Comment: @telegna I will look at getting some data on here, I am struggling to get the formatting in any viewable form so maybe SQL Fiddle may be better as you suggested. Currently it is showing the "Total Minutes Down" for all lines filtered by TOP 10, what I was wanting was the TOP 10 minutes down for each of the lines. I hope this helps.

Comment: So, in your desired output LineNoID #1 has ten rows (the ten highest [Total Minutes Down]), LineNoID #2 has ten rows (the ten highest [Total Minutes Down]), and so forth?  I can't recall if ROW_NUMBER() works in SQL 2005, but that might be a good way to filter what you're looking for - let me check and see.

Comment: @AHiggins that is correct! I will have a quick look at ROW_NUMBER() myself now, thank you.

Comment: Great!  I don't have access to a 2005 instance at the moment to give you the syntax, but from memory something like ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LineNoID ORDER BY [Total Minutes Down]) AS RowNum should go into a subquery, then SELECT everything from that query where the RowNum <= 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example based on a logging table in my own database (SQL 2012):

```
SELECT 
    IdentifyingValue,
    GroupingValue,
    RowNum,
    SummedValue
FROM 
  (
    SELECT  
        TrgTabName AS IdentifyingValue, 
        CAST(JobDate AS DATE) GroupingValue, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TrgTabName ORDER BY SUM(TrgTabNewRows) DESC) RowNum,
        SUM(TrgTabNewRows) SummedValue
    FROM DWA_JobTableCount
    GROUP BY TrgTabName, CAST(JobDate AS DATE)
  ) s
WHERE RowNum <= 3
```

You can use your base `SELECT` statement to replace the sample `s` subquery, and modify the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to use your `LineNoID` as the `PARTITION BY` and your `[Total Minutes Down]` as the `ORDER BY DESC`.  Then modify the outer query to retrieve the columns you want, and modify the outer `WHERE` clause to get the RowNum count you want.

==================================================================================

**EDIT:**
You made a good try at incorporating the code, but there are a couple of mistakes.  One of them is mine: I didn't notice that you were using a `SUM()` function in your original query, and I told you to use that field in your `ROW_NUMBER()` function.  Using any sort of aggregation in a windowed function like `ROW_NUMBER()` is not allowed, so what had to happen was a three-layer query, as opposed to the two-level query I showed you: the lowest layer is your original (including the `SUM`), the middle layer adds the `ROW_NUMBER()` and ranking to the output, and the exterior adds a filter based on the `ROW_NUMBER()`.

There are a couple of other issues here, too: you are including an alias within the incorrectly positioned `SUM()` function, which is likely the cause of the specific error you are receiving. You also have two columns called `Line ID`, and you never produce a separate column that gives you the sum of `Total Minutes Down`, even though you're trying to include it in your `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses. Finally, your filter is actually still not pointing at the column produced by the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, which is going to hurt you.

Step 1: put the grouping and aggregation in a nested query, adding the `SUM` as a separate column. While I was here, I also wrote you some updated syntax for the `JOIN` expression: use this format going forward, as the comma-JOIN is no longer recommended (as marc_s pointed out in the comments).

Step 2: add the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to produce a new column.  This uses columns (`Line ID` and `Total Minutes Down`) to generate a new column, called `RowNum`.

Step 3: retrieve your desired fields and filter for the "top" ten (which the `RowNum` field helpfully identifies).

Take a look through the following code, and let me know if it works for you.  I don't have access to your base tables, so there's a danger that I might have misnamed a field or referenced the wrong alias - it's up to you to vet my code sample to make sure it fits your database. I believe this will produce the functionality you're looking for.

```
SELECT -- returns the data you wanted originally
    [Line ID],
    [DTM Fault Code],
    [DTFC Fault Code],
    [Fault Code Occurrences],
    [Fault Name],
    [Total Minutes Down]
FROM
  (
    SELECT -- adds the row number 
        [Line ID],
        [DTM Fault Code],
        [DTFC Fault Code],
        [Fault Code Occurrences],
        [Fault Name],
        [Total Minutes Down],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Line ID] ORDER BY [Total Minutes Down] DESC) RowNum -- numbers, in descending order, the rows for each Line ID
    FROM
      (
        SELECT -- retrieves the base (aggregated) data used by the query
            DTM.[LineNoID]          as [Line ID],
            DTM.[Fault Code]        AS [DTM Fault Code],
            DTFC.[Fault Code]       AS [DTFC Fault Code], 
            COUNT(DTM.[Fault Code]) AS [Fault Code Occurrences], 
            DTFC.[Fault Name],
            SUM(DTM.[Minutes Down]) AS [Total Minutes Down] -- you still need this column to use in your output and RowNum
        FROM
            DTMain DTM 
             INNER JOIN -- note the new syntax
            DTFaultCodes DTFC ON
                DTM.[Fault Code] = DTFC.[Fault Code] -- this specifies what the relationship between the two tables is: please confirm this is correct.
             INNER JOIN 
            DTLine DTL ON 
                DTM.LineNoID = DTL.LineNoID
        WHERE DTFC.Category = 'E' -- this doesn't really need to be in the JOIN condition: because you are using INNER JOIN, it does the same thing in the WHERE clause.
        GROUP BY 
            DTM.[LineNoID],
            DTM.[Fault Code],
            DTFC.[Fault Code],
            DTFC.[Fault Name]           
      ) s1 -- the subquery at the first (lowest) level: think of it as a table with the data returned by the SELECT statement
  ) s2 -- the subquery at the second (middle) level
WHERE RowNum <= 10 -- the filter that controls the 'TOP n'
```

Comment: can you take a look over my updated SQL please and suggest where I am going wrong please?

Comment: OK, I've reviewed your SQL and made notes about the areas that need to be fixed.  I also included a code sample showing what that (probably) looks like.  Review both to be sure you understand what's going on, and let me know if this update works for you.

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly what I was after, thank you all very much for your help. Much appreciated! :)